# How to filter contacts by name with proper contact in iOS swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a `UITableView` of contacts with names and numbers. I need to filter that contacts by name. Its filtering name but not respective number. I am using this link for doing this task https://www.journaldev.com/14126/ios-uisearchcontroller-uitableview

But It has models like

```
models = [
        Model(name:"The Dark Night", number:"Action"),
        Model(name:"The Avengers", number:"Action"),
        Model(name:"Logan", number:"Action"),
        Model(name:"Shutter Island", number:"Thriller"),
        Model(name:"Inception", number:"Thriller"),
        Model(name:"Titanic", number:"Romance"),
        Model(name:"La la Land", number:"Romance"),
        Model(name:"Gone with the number", genre:"Romance"),
        Model(name:"Godfather", number:"Drama"),
        Model(name:"Moonlight", number:"Drama")
    ]
```

I am fetching `nameArr` and `numbersArr` from the server. I can not split like name:"Moonlight", number:"Drama". How can I pass my arrays instead of manual defining like that?

Comment: Can you show your attempt with the expected output and the output that you are gettting?

Comment: Where is the problem? When you filter `models` by name you have both `name` and `number`. Don't use multiple  arrays.